# software "qucs" could not be installed on 13.04; but could be installed on 12.04 by apt-get

Tags: installation, apt

Unfortunately the package "qucs" which could be installed on Ubuntu 12.04, got the following error and could not be installed on Ubuntu 13.04.

```
Package qucs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'qucs' has no installation candidate
```

I tried `apt-get update` too; But that did not solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

Qucs was removed from Ubuntu in 12.10, when Qt3 was removed, because it depended on qt3. The readme in their repository explains how to compile it, as the PPA only supports 12.10 and 12.04.

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2077639

To grab the repository: `git clone git://git.code.sf.net/p/qucs/git qucs-git`

Repository: http://sourceforge.net/p/qucs/git/ci/master/tree/